# jQuery - Strange Behavior When Using Symbol As Input To Change Element's HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange, symbols

I am creating a live content editor for an element using textarea, but its output isn't like what the expected if the inputted value is symbol like `>` or `<` or mix up of those symbols and texts, instead of just texts, then it will not replacing instead of doubled it up.

Here is the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2d5vopz7/)**

And here is the jquery codes:

```
$("#changer").on("change keyup paste", function () {
        // get current element
        var thehtml = $("#tochange").html();
        var thetext = $("#tochange").contents().filter(function () {
            return this.nodeType === 3;
        }).text().trim();
        var thechange = $(this).val();

        // if has element, then keep it, add text and put back          
        var thepurehtml = thehtml.replace(thetext, "");
        var theoutput = thechange;
        if ($.trim(thepurehtml) != '') {
            var theoutput = thechange + thepurehtml;
        }
        $("#tochange").html("").html(theoutput);
        return;
    });
```

What's causing it and how to fix it up?

**PS:** I need to have the functionality of this line `var theoutput = thechange + thepurehtml;` because it is sometimes the edited element have html element other than just a blank or text node.

Comment: PLease check this. If your motto is to edit the html through a text area. I hope [fddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2d5vopz7/4/) will help you

Answer (score 0):

**However i am going to delete this answer, As i don't have enough reputation to comment i am posting as answer.**

So @SoursopTree, **what you actually want to achieve?**

What i found is  when you enter `<`  or `>` the line `$.trim(thepurehtml)` is returning empty string (null) and `null!=''`, so the next statement  `var theoutput = thechange + thepurehtml;`  here `thechange`=`>` and `thepurehtml`=`&gt;`. so you are getting two symbols instead of one.

You said `you need to have the functionality of this line var theoutput = thechange + thepurehtml;`